# What is the correct way to trust a self-signed certificate in iOS 10.3.3?

Tags: ios, ios10.3

This is *specific* to 10.3.3. The option to trust the certificate under "Certificate Trust Settings" is no longer available to me (it was post-10.3 and pre-10.3.3). I reset my simulator and didn't realise this was an issue.

The server and certificate chain fully passes `nscurl --ats-diagnostics <url>`. The profile and certificate is installed on the device, and is verified. It contains the correct v3 required extensions, and is not SHA-1 (or other archaic options).

I can browse to the server with Safari (after the initial "verify" alert). Does anyone know what has changed in 10.3.3 and its certificate handling?

Edit: Rebuilding the certs is not a concern if required.

Comment: Aha! (This is a comment until someone can confidently corroborate.) It appears that this constraint is required `basicConstraints=CA:TRUE` -- as in it can't be absent. ref: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/x509v3_config.html